# Mvc table how to change the text color conditional

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

i would like to change the text color of a specific table column, if the model value is over - unter - equal of 0. Detailed, it will be green if the value is over zero, red unter zero and blue when it is equal.

My table is the above:

```html
<div class="row">
    <table id="RealtimeSharesTable" class="dataTable table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => dummy.RealtimeOrder)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => dummy.AlternativeName)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => dummy.Last)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => dummy.PctChange)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => dummy.Bid)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => dummy.BSize)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => dummy.Ask)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => dummy.ASize)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => dummy.Capital)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => dummy.High)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => dummy.Low)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => dummy.Volume)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (ShareViewModel item in Model.Shares)
            {
                <tr id="@item.Symbol.Replace(".", "_").Replace("=","_")">
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.RealtimeOrder)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.AlternativeName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Last)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.PctChange) %</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Bid)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.BSize)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Ask)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ASize)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Capital)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.High)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Low)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Volume)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The column that i need this to done is the "item.PctChange", depending of his price. I have tried many solution but i would like to have a suggestion from an expert.

Thank you.

Comment: Use a view model with and extra property (say) `string ClassName` and set its value (say "Red" or "Blue") based on the price in the controller before you pass it to the view, then use `<td class="@item.ClassName">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.PctChange) %</td>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my way of doing this ..

using the ternary operator directly in the `class` attribute of your `td`

the Ternary operator will be `if` `else if` `else`

ie : `item.PctChange > 0? "green" : item.PctChange == 0? "blue" : "red"`

Add a class to the `td` element which you want to color.

So change your `td` as below.

`<td class="@( item.PctChange > 0? "green" : item.PctChange == 0? "blue" : "red")">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.PctChange) %</td>`

Also have a CSS rule for the classes to color the `td` accordingly.

```
.green{
  background-color:green;
 }

.blue{
  background-color:blue;
 }

.green{
  background-color:red;
 }
```