# Changing font colour conditionally in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to MVC and still learning the best way to go about things.

My problem is I want to change a font colour conditionally. For example, if something gets deleted. I want the font colour of the item to change to red.

For reference I will add the relevant data to this question below.

**VIEW** (What I want to be changed to red when deleted)

```
<div class="well text-center">
  <h1><b>Purchase Order @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrderID)</b></h1>    
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder = db.PurchaseOrders.Find(id);
    purchaseOrder.deleted = !purchaseOrder.deleted;
    db.SaveChanges();
    db.Entry(purchaseOrder).Reference("Supplier").Load();
    if (purchaseOrder.deleted)
    {
        TempData["message"] = string.Format("Purchase Order - {0} has been deleted\nCompany: {1}\nExpected Date:{2}\nNotes:{3}\n\nLink: {4}/PurchaseOrders/Details/{5}", purchaseOrder.ID, purchaseOrder.Supplier.Company, purchaseOrder.DeliveryDate, purchaseOrder.Details, IGT.baseUrl, purchaseOrder.ID);
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["message"] = string.Format("Purchase Order - {0} has been undeleted\nCompany: {1}\nExpected Date:{2}\nNotes:{3}\n\nLink: {4}/PurchaseOrders/Details/{5}", purchaseOrder.ID, purchaseOrder.Supplier.Company, purchaseOrder.DeliveryDate, purchaseOrder.Details, IGT.baseUrl, purchaseOrder.ID);

    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mvc table how to change the text color conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690377/mvc-table-how-to-change-the-text-color-conditional)

Answer (score 1):

Just keep things simple :)

Put a span around the DisplayFor and use a ternary operator on the deleted property to set a css class that will either turn the text red if deleted or a different color if not.

```
<div class="well text-center">
  <h1>
     <b>Purchase Order <span class="@(Model.deleted ? "DeletedCSSClass" : "ActiveCSSClass")"> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrderID)</span></b>
  </h1>    
</div>
```

Comment: I don't like having these conditional statement all over the views. They will quickly become messy.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Regardless of personal preference, view logic belongs in the view. Separation of concerns is key.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your using bootstrap so here's one approach.

Create a class representing your colours:

```
public sealed class TextColour
{
    public string CssClass { get; }

    private static IDictionary<string, TextColour> _instances = new Dictionary<string, TextColour>();

    private TextColour(string cssClass)
    {
        CssClass = cssClass;
    }

    private static TextColour GetInstance(string cssClass)
    {
        if (!_instances.ContainsKey(cssClass))
        {
            _instances[cssClass] = new TextColour(cssClass);
        }

        return _instances[cssClass];
    }

    public static TextColour Primary => GetInstance("text-primary");
    public static TextColour Secondary => GetInstance("text-secondary");

    // Add others here
}
```

Add a property to your view model:

```
public class PurchaseOrderModel
{
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public TextColour TextColour => Deleted ? TextColour.Primary : TextColour.Secondary;
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<div class="well text-center @Model.TextColour.CssClass">
  <h1><b>Purchase Order @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrderID)</b></h1>    
</div>
```

Comment: Why even use a MVC pattern if you are just going to inject style logic in models?

Comment: @Travis view models pertain **only** to the view. It is not in the domain entity.